# Error al conectarme desde android a api en laravel

Tags: java, android, android-studio, laravel, api

Cuando intento conectarme a api de laravel con android studio me bota el error:

> **Failed to connect to /127.0.0.0:8000**

esta es la url  que uso http://127.0.0.0:8000/api/

La pruebo con postman y me funciona.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: Con que codigo has probado? cual es el error?

Comment: Me parece que el problema está que 127.0.0.1 desde postman en tu pc, es tu pc. Y 127.0.0.1 desde android, es el dispositivo android. Por un lado tenés que usar la dirección de la intranet de tu pc, y por otro probablemente abrir el puerto 8000 en el firewall. Y la api debe estar configurada para escuchar en todas las interfaces de red para que funcione tanto con 127.0.0.1 como con la dirección de la intranet (configuración del servidor web).